# how to get result as 'ARRAY of objects' in postgresql query?

Tags: postgresql

I am selecting rows as

```
`SELECT
jsonb_build_object('platform_id',pl.id,'platform_Name',pl."name") as "platform" from
"platforms" as pl ON pl.id = up."platform_id" 
WHERE usrs.id = ${userid}`
```

I am getting result as JSON

```
"platform": {
                "platform_id": 5,
                "platform_Name": "Snapchat"
            }
```

but I want the platform result as "array of object " like below

DESIRED RESULT :

```
 "platform": [{
                    "platform_id": 5,
                    "platform_Name": "Snapchat"
                }]
```

How to make write query to get it as  array ?

Comment: Use the JSON_AGG() aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated a similar example with:

```
create table platforms (id int, name text, user_id int);
insert into platforms values (1, 'snapchat',100),(2, 'fb', 100),(3, 'instagram', 200), (4, 'twitter',100);
```

The `platforms` table contains:

```
 id |   name    | user_id
----+-----------+---------
  1 | snapchat  |     100
  2 | fb        |     100
  3 | instagram |     200
  4 | twitter   |     100
(4 rows)
```

You can solve the problem in 2 steps:

1. create the json object with `id` and `name` using `jsonb_build_object`
2. aggregate over `user_id` using `jsonb_agg`

the query is

```
with create_doc as (
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    jsonb_build_object('platform_id',id,'platform_Name',name) as platform 
from platforms
)
select user_id, jsonb_agg(platform) from create_doc group by user_id;
```

result

```
 user_id |                                                                   json_agg
---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     200 | [{"platform_id": 3, "platform_Name": "instagram"}]
     100 | [{"platform_id": 1, "platform_Name": "snapchat"}, {"platform_id": 2, "platform_Name": "fb"}, {"platform_id": 4, "platform_Name": "twitter"}]
(2 rows)
```